# AES шифрования. Коллизия ли?

Tags: c#, python, aes

Сейчас приходится переписывать для одного проекта код с python на c#. Сам проект представляет из себя шифрование данных. Так вот в процессе работы переписал код, но переписанная прога отказывается правильно работать, в отличие от исходной на python. Стал проверять все хеши и шифры и наткнулся на такую вещь. При AES дешифровании данных возникает коллизия, python и c# на первый взгляд выдают правильные результаты, но присмотревшись заметил, что выходные данные отличаются на один символ в одном случае, в во втором c# приписывает еще несколько символов в конец.

Python:
    0a053d408ed27bf0132168fd510f91e4ada483b49c5781219d0**a**448d267338eb

C#:
    0a053d408ed27bf0132168fd510f91e4ada483b49c5781219d0**d**448d267338eb

Второй случай:

Python:
    ecca0154affd0860e11638fe7bab3f5396c74153b56cf4346c5c27b9ece1

C#:
   ecca0154affd0860e11638fe7bab3f5396c74153b56cf4346c5c27b9ece1**0087**

Как быть в таком случае? Можно ли как то исправить это или в чем ошибка?

```
                AES.KeySize = 192;
                AES.BlockSize = 128;
                AES.IV = new byte[16];
                AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                AES.Key = Key;
```

Comment: По второму случаю у C# верные данные (два блока по 128 бит), а Питон не дописывает полностью второй блок.

Comment: Может конечно просто отображение неправильное, в по факту все так, но вот к первому случаю у меня прям вопросище

Comment: Тут без изначальных данных (ключ и данные которые шифруются) вряд ли что то можно сказать. Может и коллизия, но это крайне маловероятно.

Comment: Приведите коды на обоих языках, которые позволят воспроизвести ситуацию, ну и версии используемых библиотек на всякий случай